# how i can do some function after client's push inline keyboard button in telegram chat

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I need to do some function after push inline keyboard button in telegram chat (eg. send a pic or use some api and send json from api). In docs of telegram-bot-api i can't find what i should do.

```
def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    if query.data == '1':
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('', get_pic))
    elif query.data == '2':
        query.edit_message_text(text="Mosc".format(query.data))
    elif query.data == '3':
        query.edit_message_text(text="SaintP".format(query.data))
```

i expect that after first 'if' user of telegram chat can see the 'get_pic' function

Comment: sorry for my question, i'm newbie in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case after click on mp3 InlineButton call my function actually you have so much option to do

```
try:  
    data = update.callback_query.data
    link = cache.get(f'{user_id}_link')
    if data == 'Mp3':
        bot.send_message(user_id, WAITING)
        bot.send_chat_action(user_id, action=telegram.ChatAction.FIND_LOCATION)
        download_send_youtube(link, user_id, bot, 'mp3') # my function
        return "youtube"
except AttributeError:
    pass
```